# pass parameters through variable to WP_QUERY

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to use the plugin PrivateContent to limit access to certain pages/categories. I have a function (getAllowedCategories()) which reads PrivateContent access levels for the current user and outputs a list of category IDs which the user has access to. I'm trying to use this to build a foreach() loop that passes each ID to a WP_QUERY and generates the latest two posts in that category. But when I try to use a variable as WP_QUERY's parameter, it does no filtering at all. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$currentCats = getAllowedCategories($user_data);
foreach ($currentCats as $currentCat) { 
    echo $currentCat . "<br/>";
    $parameters = "'category__in=" . $currentCat . "'";
    $aj_query = new WP_Query( $parameters );

    if ( $aj_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $aj_query->have_posts() ) {
            $aj_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: is currentCat an array?

Comment: No, currentCat is a single number, and it's different every pass through the loop. I concatenated that number with the required wordpress parameter in `$parameters`, so I can't see what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping your parameters string in unnecessary layer of quotes:

- `$parameters = "'category__in=1'";` — wrong
- `$parameters = 'category__in=1';` — right

It is usually preferable to use arrays for query arguments:

- `$parameters = [ 'category__in' => 1 ];`

Comment: I've changed that, but I'm not sure how else to get the $currentCat in there. The problem is still occurring: WP_QUERY seems to want a number there, but all I have is a variable. Shouldn't it be the same thing? In your example, I can't just type `category__in=1` because I don't have the number, only `$currentCat`. And `$parameters = 'cat= $currentCat ';` doesn't work.

Comment: @authorandrew Use double quotes, if you want to do it like this - read [PHP Manual: Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more info. Or you just use an array as suggested, just replace the 1 with the variable.

Comment: @authorandrew Arrays would be the preferred and cleaner solution IMO but as strings you could: "category__in={$currentCat}"

Comment: `$parameters = [ 'category__in' => $currentCat ];
$aj_query = new WP_Query( $parameters );`
This code gives me the white screen of death.

Comment: When I echo $currentCat it gives me a single number only. Could it be passing something I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Works fine when I use an explicit number in the QUERY, as follows: `$aj_query = new WP_Query( 'category__in=4' );`

Comment: If short array syntax is giving you WSoD it's most likely you are running obsolete PHP version and need to update.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress code guide tripped me up on this one. It was wrapping query parameters in single quotes -- which works, when everything is plain text (e.g. `$aj_query = new WP_Query( 'category__in=4');`)

There's no need for a $parameters variable to pass into `WP_QUERY` (though I assume this method might work as well) By ditching the single quotes and just passing `$currentCat` directly into `WP_QUERY`, everything filters exactly right. The final code for the query is as follows:

`$aj_query = new WP_Query( "category__in=" . $currentCat);`

This will read the variable correctly and return all posts directly in that category (not children posts -- if you want to include child categories, use `"cat"` instead of `"category__in"`.